# Name delimiters in biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to replace all name delimiters by "--", so it shall be "Author1 -- Author2 -- Author3" instead of "Author1, Author2 and Author3".

Currently I am using this code:

```
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,bibstyle=authortitle,sorting=nyt,dashed=false,%
maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}


\newcounter{mymaxcitenames}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{mymaxcitenames}{\value{maxnames}}%
}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \printtext[brackets]{%
    \begingroup
    \defcounter{maxnames}{\value{mymaxcitenames}}%
    \printnames{labelname}%
    \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:labelyear+extrayear}%
    \endgroup
    }%
  \quad% or \addspace
}
```

I hope someone can help me - I am trying to get a bibliography which fits the rules of Deutsches Archäologisches Institut (DAI).

Answer (score 7):

To change the delimiters to, e.g., dashes both for citations and in the bibliography, add the following to your preamble:

```
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}
```

Preamble code for changing the delimiters only in the bibliography:

```
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}%
}
```

Preamble code for changing the delimiters only for citations:

```
\let\oldmultinamedelim\multinamedelim
\let\oldfinalnamedelim\finalnamedelim
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{~--\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{~--\space}
\AtBeginBibliography{%
  \renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\oldmultinamedelim}%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\oldfinalnamedelim}%
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the biblatex-style [`archaeologie`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/archaeologie)  which covers the citation rules of the Deutsches Archäologisches Institut (German Archaeological Institute).

Furthermore you can cite ancient works with this style.

See the description of the style in [English](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/archaeologie/archaeologie.pdf) and a short description in [German](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/archaeologie/archaeologie-ger.pdf).

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[           
  backend=biber,
  style=archaeologie,
  lstpublishers,
  lstabbrv,
  width=6em,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{archaeologie-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{Cosa1949,Evangelidis2014,Mastrocinque2012,Mann2011,Fentress2003}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And these bibliography entries:

```
@Article{Cosa1949,
  title        = {Cosa},
  subtitle     = {Republican Colony in Etruria},
  journaltitle = ClJ,
  shortjournal = ClJ-short,
  volume       = {45},
  pages        = {141--149},
  year         = {1949},
  label        = {Cosa},
  number       = {1},
}

@Article{Evangelidis2014,
  author       = {Evangelidis, Vasilis},
  title        = {Agoras {and} Fora},
  subtitle     = {Developments in the Central Public Space of the Cities of Greece during the {Roman} Period},
  journaltitle = BSA,
  shortjournal = BSA-short,
  volume       = {109},
  pages        = {335--356},
  year         = {2014},
  doi          = {10.1017/s006824541400015x},
}

@Article{Mastrocinque2012,
  author  = {Mastrocinque, Attilio and Saggioro, Fabio},
  title   = {Magnetometry at Grumentum in Ancient Lucania},
  pages   = {1--5},
  year    = {2012},
  url     = {www.fastionline.org/docs/FOLDER-it-2012-245.pdf},
  urldate = {2015-07-21},
  journal = {The Journal of Fasti Online},
}

@Book{Mann2011,
  author    = {Mann, Christian},
  title     = {\enquote{Um keinen Kranz, um das Leben kämpfen wir!}},
  subtitle  = {Gladiatoren im Osten des Römischen Reiches und die Frage der Romanisierung},
  publisher = {Verlag Antike},
  location  = Berlin,
  year      = {2011},
  series    = {Studien zur Alten Geschichte},
  number    = {14},
}

@Incollection{Fentress2003,
  author       = {Fentress, Elizabeth and John Bodel and Adam Rabinowitz and Rabun Taylor},
  title        = {Cosa in the Republic and Early Empire},
  pages        = {13--62},
  editor       = {Fentress, Elizabeth},
  booktitle    = {An Intermittent Town},
  booksubtitle = {Excavations 1991--1997},
  publisher    = UMP,
  location     = {Ann Arbor, Mich.},
  year         = {2003},
  volume       = {V},
  series       = MemAmAc,
  number       = {2},
  maintitle    = {Cosa},
  shortseries  = MemAmAc-short,
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[lockstep](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/510/lockstep)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57622/35864) still works, but things are a bit easier now with the context-sensitive delimiter interface.

In order to change the delimiter for citations and the bibliography use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace--\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{companion}
sit \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson – Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor (Goossens – Mittelbach – Samarin 1994) sit (Aksın et al. 2006) Aksın, Özge et al. (2006). ‘Effect of immobilization on catalytic characterist- ics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions’. In: J. Organomet. Chem. 691.13, pp. 3027–3036. Goossens, Michel – Frank Mittelbach – Alexander Samarin (1994). The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley. 528 pp. Nussbaum, Martha (1978). Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Prin- ceton University Press. Sigfridsson, Emma – Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096- 987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

In order to change just the bibliography

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace--\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{companion}
sit \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor (Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin 1994) sit (Aksın et al. 2006) Aksın, Özge et al. (2006). ‘Effect of immobilization on catalytic characterist- ics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions’. In: J. Organomet. Chem. 691.13, pp. 3027–3036. Goossens, Michel – Frank Mittelbach – Alexander Samarin (1994). The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley. 528 pp. Nussbaum, Martha (1978). Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Prin- ceton University Press. Sigfridsson, Emma – Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096- 987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

For just the citations, use

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace--\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{companion}
sit \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson – Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor (Goossens – Mittelbach – Samarin 1994) sit (Aksın et al. 2006) Aksın, Özge et al. (2006). ‘Effect of immobilization on catalytic characterist- ics of saturated Pd-N-heterocyclic carbenes in Mizoroki-Heck reactions’. In: J. Organomet. Chem. 691.13, pp. 3027–3036. Goossens, Michel, Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin (1994). The LaTeX Companion. 1st ed. Reading, Mass.: Addison-Wesley. 528 pp. Nussbaum, Martha (1978). Aristotle’s ‘De Motu Animalium’. Princeton: Prin- ceton University Press. Sigfridsson, Emma and Ulf Ryde (1998). ‘Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments’. In: Journal of Computational Chemistry 19.4, pp. 377–395. doi: 10.1002/(SICI)1096- 987X(199803)19:4<377::AID-JCC1>3.0.CO;2-P.]

If you just want to change one particular citation command, you can use the same strategy that we used for the bibliography

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[textcite]{multinamedelim}{\addnbspace--\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[textcite]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \textcite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \textcite{nussbaum}
dolor \textcite{companion}
sit \textcite{aksin}

Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{nussbaum}
dolor \autocite{companion}
sit \autocite{aksin}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem Sigfridsson – Ryde (1998) ipsum Nussbaum (1978) dolor Goossens – Mittelbach – Samarin (1994) sit Aksın et al. (2006) Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (Nussbaum 1978) dolor (Goossens, Mittelbach and Samarin 1994) sit (Aksın et al. 2006)]