# Citation format and style in biber

Tags: biblatex, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Name delimiters in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54644/name-delimiters-in-biblatex)

I'm trying to format my citations according to my supervisors wishes and getting stuck.

The first problem is getting citations with parentheses right. I summon it with the latex `\citep{alpha2013}`.  This is fine for single names like (Alpha, 2013) and many names like (Aplha et al., 2013), however when there is only two names I get (Alpha, Beta, 2013) and my super wants (Alpha & Beta, 2013).  How do I get this?

The second problem is that written in line like Alpha (2013) and I don't know how to do this.  Currently I use `\cite{beta}` and I get Alpha, 2013.  In addition, my super wants to have the same style as before where if there is only 2 authors, it becomes Alpha & Beta (2013).

My preamble is thus:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    block=space,
    date=long,
    doi=false,
    eprint=false,
    firstinits=true,
    isbn=false,
    minnames=2,
    maxnames=2,
    mincitenames=2,
    maxcitenames=2,
    natbib=true,
    sortcites=false,
    sorting=nyt,
    style=authoryear-comp,
    terseinits=true,
    uniquelist=false,
    uniquename=false,
    url=false
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{../../BibTex/library.bib}

%Put initials after names...
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}    
%Remove "and" before last name. However, this also removes "and" in a textcite...
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
```

Now I know that if you remove the last line in the preamble `\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}` I get 'and' in the citation, but its how to get '&' instead that I don't know.

Comment: Re problem 1: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54644/name-delimiters-in-biblatex (use `\&\space` instead of `~--\space`). Re problem 2: Use `\citet` (or `\textcite`) for citations "in the flow of the text".

Comment: @lockstep that seems to fix it :)  Thanks.  If you write it up as an answer, I'll mark it accepted :)

Comment: In the case at hand, I'd prefer an upvote to my linked answer -- the questions are very similar.

Comment: Maybe for your next `biblatex` question. :-) Spotting a possible duplicate and then providing an answer nevertheless is somewhat frowned upon.

Comment: @lockstep I'm not entirely sure it is a duplicate.  It's only maybe a quarter duplicate since the linked question didn't give me the `\&\space` I needed in the first half, and didn't answer any of the second half of my question :)  But I'm happy to defer to experience :)