# BibTex problem with multiple names in author field despite using "and"

Tags: bibtex

I'm new to StackExchange!

I have this document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,italian]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}

Questa è una citazione \cite{Citation}.

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

And this bibliography:

```
@misc{Citation,
author = "Daniele Vietri and Francesca Castelli",
title = "M-commerce in Italia",
howpublished = {\url{http://www.dblog.it/ecommerce/}},
year = {2012},
note = {[accesso: Marzo 2013]}
}
```

Why do I get the following output? It's making me crazy...

[image]

I would like to have a comma in place of "and".

And why the first letter of the word "Italia" in the title becomes lower-case?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: For the last question, add braces around the I (`{I}talia`), see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file

Comment: @Torbjørn I did not expect an answer so quickly, thank you! Your solution for the title works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

which in turn specifies that lists of names should be formatted by this readable bit of code:

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                { "," * }
                'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

somewhere in the middle of that you will see it adds `,` or `and` or `et al` depending on the number of names left in the list.

You could tinker with that, although you should not change the default file, or more easily find another bibtex style that does what you want. (perhaps use the `makebst` package to make one). You need to decide what you want to do for lists of length 0,1,2,3 and more than N for some N.

You want `a, b` not `a and b` but what do you want for a list of three, the normal choices are either `a, b, and c` or `a, b and c` but perhaps you want `a, b, c` (If you do want that you can just change `and` in a copy of the above to `,` I think.

Comment: I finally solved using a different style (ama.bst) which does exactly what I wanted, even with more than 2 names (a, b, c). Thank you very much for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on a [previous question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54644/name-delimiters-in-biblatex), and it uses at its core the `biblatex` package (which provides a powerful replacement to the classic LaTeX and bibTeX duo).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside,italian]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblio}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\begin{document}

Questa è una citazione \cite{Citation}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Additional stuff. Together with the `babel` and `csquotes` packages you should get a decent support for Italian conventions. For example, if you comment the line where we redefine the `\finalnamedelim` command, you will get the Italian "e" in place of the English "and". Also, the command `\printbibliography` automatically prints a heading for the bibliography which is language dependent, in this case "Riferimenti bibliograci", but you can give it the argument `[heading={text}]` to choose whatever you need.

Also, I used the `hyperref` package instead of the `url` package, because it creates actual hyperlinks (I think it loads the `url` package automatically).

Comment: I had never used before biblatex so I preferred to simply try another style. Thanks anyway for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason to want `a, b` instead of `a and b` (which is the standard)?

If so, you should find either a style that does that or make one yourself like David Carlise says, though there should be a really good reason to do that (and not just "I just like it that way"). Things in LaTeX are done for a very good reason, most of the times following what standards dictates.

A few comments on your bib entry:

- Authors should be written `Lastname, Names`, i.e.:

  `author = {Vietri, Daniele and Castelli, Francesca and Mozart, Wolfgang Amadeus}`
- Depending on the style, it will manage titles in different ways (i.e. capitalizing all letters, the first letter of a word, etc.). You should write the titltes in a consistent way. If you know that some word must have some capitalization (like Italy, IEEE, etc) you can force it like this:

  `title = {M-commerce in {I}talia},`