# Change author separator and delete "&" in bibliography (biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I have some problems with the bibliography.
  For nearly all changes I wanted I found solutions, but not for these two:

1: I would like to change the separator after the first name: "Panzer, Paul; Mustermann, Max" instead of "Panzer, Paul, Mustermann, Max".

2: How can I change the "&" to a ";" (but just in the bibliography and not in citations!)

Thank you very much :-)

This is the code I use:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc, titlepage]{scrartcl} 

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{filecontents} 

    \usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
    \usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,natbib=true, maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,uniquelist=false, backend=biber]{biblatex}
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\textsc{#1}} 

    \DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{ 
       andothers = {{et\,al\adddot}},            
    } 

    \renewcommand{\finalnamedelim}[0]{\addspace\&\addspace}  

    \DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first} 
    \DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}  

    \DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{citetitle}{#1} %Anführungszeichen um Titel entfernen
    \DeclareFieldFormat[article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,patent,thesis,unpublished]{title}{#1} 

    \addbibresource{literature.bib} 

    \begin{filecontents}{literature.bib} 

    @Article{Pa2015,
      Title                    = {The Test},
      Author                   = {Paul Panzer and Max Mustermann and Bananen Baum},
      Journaltitle             = {bla bla},
      Year                     = {2015},

      Owner                    = {Me},
      Timestamp                = {2014.08.14}
    }
    \end{filecontents} 


    \begin{document}

    test \parencite{Pa2015}\\

    \printbibliography


    It should look like this:\\

    \textsc{Panzer}, Paul; \textsc{Mustermann}, Max; \textsc{Baum}, Bananen (2015). The test. In: \textit{bla bla.}\\



    \end{document}
```

Comment: See also the (generically named) [Name delimiters in biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/54644/35864).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your first issue you want to change `multinamedelim`, in your case maybe to

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

It does not make a difference in this example, but I would be tempted to say

```
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
```

to change the delimiter only in the bibliography and let the citations keep the comma.

---

For the second item, you want

```
\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
```

to get "&" in citations and

```
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
```

to change back to ";" in the bibliography.

---

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,DIV=calc, titlepage]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxbibnames=9,maxcitenames=2,
  uniquelist=false,
  natbib=true,
]{biblatex}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{
  andothers = {et\,al\adddot},
}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat{finalnamedelim}{\addspace\&\space}
\DeclareDelimAlias[bib]{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}


\DeclareFieldFormat[
  article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,
  patent,thesis,unpublished
]{citetitle}{#1}

\DeclareFieldFormat[
  article,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,
  patent,thesis,unpublished
]{title}{#1}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Pa2015,
  Title        = {The Test},
  Author       = {Paul Panzer and Max Mustermann and Bananen Baum},
  Journaltitle = {bla bla},
  Year         = {2015},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
test \autocite{Pa2015}

\autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography

It should look like this:

\textsc{Panzer}, Paul; \textsc{Mustermann}, Max; \textsc{Baum}, Bananen (2015).
The test. In: \textit{bla bla.}
\end{document}
```

[image: test (Panzer etal., 2015) (Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998) Panzer, Paul; Mustermann, Max; Baum, Bananen (2015). The Test. In: bla bla. Sigfridsson, Emma; Ryde, Ulf (1998).]

*Note* this answer was updated to use context-sensitive delimiters. If you use an ancient version of `biblatex` and the commands are not available, have a look at the edit history.