# Apply biblatex macro changes to either citations or bibliography entries

Tags: biblatex

I want the macro `\finalnamedelim` to behave differently for the citations and bib entries.

Especially in the case of **exactly two** authors (if we have more, the citation style uses "et al" anyway), in the citation it should use "and" as a seperator, but a **comma** in the bib entry.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[%
    style=authoryear,
    bibstyle=authoryear,
    maxcitenames=2,
    dashed=false,
    firstinits=true
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
% ----------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\parencite{bertram}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Which results in this citation:
[image]
and this bib entry:
[image]

However I want to achieve this:
[image]
[image]

What is the best way to do that?

Best regards,
David

Comment: `\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}}`? Then the standard is used for citations and in the bibliography it is changed to a comma with space. Cf. the general approach used in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/57622/35864

Comment: @moewe Hey, that was easier than expected. Thank you!

Comment: Do you think your question is a duplicate of the one linked to or do you want an answer?

Comment: I don't think, thats it is an actual duplicate - the linked answer just applies well to this also. I could maybe change the title to something like "Apply biblatex macro changes to either citations or the bibliography" to make it more apparent if someone searches for a solution like this.

Comment: OK, if you would like an answer instead I can write one up.

Comment: I'd appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply certain settings to the bibliography only using the `\AtBeginBibliography` hook

```
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}}
```

---

The `\AtEveryCite` hooks does the same for citations, so you could, in principle, also go with

```
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\AtEveryCite{%
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
    \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}}
```

but why would you?

---

There are also `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\AtEveryBibitem`, those hooks are executed in a context where the bibliographic data of the entry in question is already available. This is not important for the commands used here, but `\clearfield` and friends will only work with `\AtEveryCitekey` and `\AtEveryBibitem`.

You can read more about these code hooks in §4.10.6 *General Purpose Hooks*, pp. 244-246, of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).